# API Endpoint for Files and Folders

Tags: ms-office

Hi I am trying to retrieve a list of all files and folders using the REST API as described here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Since I will be working with files and folders can anyone please tell me what is API Endpoint for retrieving files and folders.
For example, The API Endpoint for Discovery service is: https://api.office.com/discovery/me" 
AND
for Mail, Calenddar and Contacts API its : https//outlook.office365.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding that the endpoint is specific to the O365 tenant, for example https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jim_contoso_com/_api.

Again, it's my understanding that you can use the Discovery service's https://api.office.com/discovery/me/Services endpoint (by including an access token authorization header) to get the user specific service endpoint, however it looks like the Discovery service is broken. It was working a few weeks ago, but not today.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. It seems that  https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jim_contoso_com/_api works on the browser but not when I make a REST call. Have you had any problems with this before?

Comment: I have mmanaged to fix this issue now. It was a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an error but not using the latest tools. You should update your tools to Visual Studio 2013 UPdate 2 and pull down the new tools for the Office 365 API Preview from within the IDE. This will allow you to support a lot more project types as mentioned in the blog post http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your reply. I am getting an 403 error when I try and retrieve all the files. This even after I have given full control over "My Files".  I will update my tools as you recommended and try it again. Many thanks.